# How would I find the next largest number in an Array?

Tags: java

I'm having trouble figuring out how to find the next biggest number in an Array. For example; if I am given the number 5, from the array [1,2,3,4,5,7,4,6] how do I find that 6 is the next biggest number

Comment: `Arrays.stream(arr).filter(n -> n > 5).min().getAsInt()`

Comment: Please clarify: are the answers addressing your question, or is something missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Basically there are two options here:

- you can first *sort* that array, for example by using the sort method provided by java.utils.Arrays. Then you simply iterate through the array, to first search for that given number. When you found that, the next number you encounter (that isn't your given number) is the next biggest one.
- or, more efficient: you iterate the array, and check each entry "is it bigger than my given number?" If that is the case, you remember that value. The next time you encounter such a "bigger as given number", you compare it with the last one you found, and keep the smaller one. In other words: you simply search for the minimum number in an array but you have to include that condition "bigger than the given number".

Please consider this as inspiration to do the coding yourself. You learn programming by doing exactly that, not by delegating the heavy lifting to other people.

Answer (score -1):

I got you homie

```
int numGiven = 0;

    //assign number that is given.
    numGiven = 5;

    int nextHighest = 0;

    int[] arrayNum = {1,2,3,4,5,7,4,6};

    boolean nextHighestNumberIsFound = false;

    boolean endOfLoop = false;

    while(endOfLoop == false && nextHighestNumberIsFound == false)
    {
        ++numGiven;
        for(int x = 0; x < arrayNum.length; x++) 
        {
            if(numGiven == arrayNum[x])
            {
                nextHighestNumberIsFound = true;
                endOfLoop = true;
                nextHighest = arrayNum[x];
                x += arrayNum.length;
            }
        }

        endOfLoop = true;
    }

    if(nextHighest != 0){
        System.out.println(nextHighest);
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("NumberSpecified is too high");
    }
```

Comment: A) we don't throw code at people without explanations B) we especially do not do the complete homework for people C) when we do, we give them a simple solution. Your code is pretty complex and hard to understand.

Comment: So, simply test with `int[] arrayNum = {1,2,3,4,5,7,4,8};` ... and surprise, your code prints "too high". Because ... due to the fact that the outer loop does NOT loop, you only do ++numGiven once. Of course, if the outer loop would loop, it could loop forever.